# leaflet markercluster single marker color

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I successfully create a clustermarkergroup with custom style. But I can't change the color of the black marker when there is only one marker in the cluster, please see image [Black marker when alone in the cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hedkc.png)

How to change that default marker color?

Here is how I create the clustergroup

```
var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();

        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster marker-mycluster', iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
    }
})
```

Some CSS

```
.marker-mycluster {
background-color: rgba(255,191,84, 0.6);
}
.marker-mycluster div {
background-color: rgba(255,191,84, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your single black marker is just your normal marker, outside any cluster since it is far away from other markers.

If you want to replace the visual appearance of ALL your markers, including when they do not cluster (i.e. when they are shown as single markers), you can conveniently use the [`singleMarkerMode` option](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options) of MarkerCluster plugin:

```js
var clusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
    singleMarkerMode: true,
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            // your code
        });
    }
})
```

This will override the icon of all your markers, so that they look like clusters of size 1.

Comment: That works well and might be our solution. But I think I prefer to have the normal marker when it is away from other markers. How can I change the color of this marker?

Comment: You simply have to specify a custom icon to your marker, either using the [`icon` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-icon) at marker instantiation, or later using the [`marker.setIcon` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon). You have to build a new [icon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) to pass to the option or method.

Comment: Just in case, the mapbox's way of customizing markers: https://www.mapbox.com/guides/an-open-platform/#simplestyle with full details at: https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec/tree/master/1.1.0